# How can I delete all commits before a given date in Git history?

Tags: git

Given a repository, I want to delete all commits that were before a particular commit, or a date in history.

I have around 10000 commits in my repository, and I want to only keep the last 1000 or so, and delete the rest. Basically what I want to do is to say *move the first commit forward to X*.

At first I thought I could just rebase and squash all of those commits into one, but that causes a lot of merge conflicts during the rebase. If there was a way to squash commits such that the version after the squash is the last commit, that'd work too.

Comment: Can you give more information? Because if you do that, you will end up to delete all the first commits of your repository! Which is impossible. What do you really want to do? Perhaps create a new root in your repository and rebase only the commit you want onto this commit.

Comment: Updated with more info. Basically I just want to erase a big portion of the history, while keeping the latest commits.

Comment: To put this in another words, I want to squash a few thousands of commits into one, ignoring merge conflicts and only keeping the state of the repo at the last commit in the range.

Comment: @JakubArnold This is like sawing off the branch you're sitting on. Not good. You can do that with `git filter-branch`, as shown in Brian's answer, but tread carefully.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, this is something that should only be done with care, and shouldn't be taken lightly. However, sometimes it is necessary; a product that was proprietary going open source, and you need to excise some code copyrighted by other people, or you didn't realize that you shouldn't commit large binary blobs to `git` and did a lot of that early on and now need to clean it up so you're not carrying that history around forever, or something of the sort. There are some valid reasons to do it, though it's generally best to try not to get in those situations to begin with.

Answer (score 27):

Warning: the following is dangerous, as it rewrites history. Always make sure you have a backup of your repo before doing any kind of major history rewriting like this.

Replace the hash in the following with the hash of the parent of the commit you want to have as your new first commit.

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter '
    read parent
    if [ "$parent" = "-p 5bdd44e5919cb0a95a9924817529cd7c980f88b5" ]
    then
        echo
    else
        echo "$parent"
    fi'
```

This rewrites the parents of each commit; for most commits, it leaves them the same, but the one with the parent matching the given hash, it replaces with an empty parent, meaning it will now become a commit with no parent. This will detach all of your old history.

Note that if what you want to be your first commit is a merge commit, you'll need to match against something like `-p parent1 -p parent2 -p parent3` for each of the parents of the merge commit, in the correct order.

If you want to apply this to all branches and tags instead of just the current branch, pass in `--all` at the end of the command (after the script).

After you have done this, and checked that it worked properly, you can delete the original branch and run a `gc` to clean out the now unreferenced commits:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Note that since `git` tends to try to preserve data, in order to actually free up the space you will also have to remove the commits from your reflog, and then run the `gc` to clean it up.

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all --all
git gc --prune=all
```

If you are not doing this to save space or eradicate the old commits, you can keep the old history around in a branch, such as `git branch old-master refs/original/refs/heads/master`; you can even "virtually reattach" it using [`git replace`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace), at which point you would have two unconnected histories (so when you push to a remote repo, you'll only push the truncated history) but when you look through history in your local repo you will see the full history.

Comment: My commit count decreased, but I can still see my commits history on github after applying your solution. Any ideas?

Comment: i tried this, i copied repo first using `cp -a` because i wanted all branches, then when i ran this, all that happened according to git log, is the commit that i wanted to be the first is now missing, but all the prior commits are still there which is what i wanted gone.  I wouldn't use this until you can get a better answer.

Comment: Hi Brian.  This seems to be a pretty elegant solution.  Thank you.  I stupidly cloned a repository in which I did not need all the commits, and forgot about the depth parameter.  This procedure, while a bit time consuming appears to have worked.

Comment: Hi Brian.  While this worked for what was specifically asked, it was not the right question, I suppose.   My Repository is now 1.6 GB, and it was 1.1GB before this procedure.  I suppose the better question for me is how to reduce the size of the repository.  I only need the data from about 4 commits.

Answer (score 10):

The simpler for me is to use `git replace` ( edit: successfully tested!).

First squash all the commit you want into one:
(we will call  the sha of the last commit you want to squash
and  the sha of the very first commit, so your root commit)

```
git checkout -b big_squash <LastSha>
git reset --soft <RootSha>
git commit --amend -m "My new root"
```

Now, you must have your branch `big_squash` pointing toward a new root (called here `<NewRootSha>`. We are here just interested by the sha1 and the branch could be deleted in the end once you complete successfully the operation).

Then you have 2 possibilities:

- Do a `git rebase --onto` of the later commits if it's easily done (that's the preferred solution of the git book but after a successful test of the other solution, that's not mine ;) )
- Use `git replace` to **hide** the old history (history is still in the repository! But we will make it permanent with a `git filter-branch`)

To replace the last commit you want to squash with the newly created commit:

```
git replace <RootSha> <NewRootSha>
```

Now, you could do a `git filter-branch` after the `git replace` to make it permanent!

After your replace, do:

```
git filter-branch master, <put here the name of all your branches>
```

*If the result suits you*, then go delete the folder `.git/refs/original` (which contains all the saved refs before the `git filter-branch`) and  the folder `.git/refs/replace` (which contains the replacement that you don't need anymore).

This solution has the advantage to be simple and revertible (except the last step once you've deleted the folders ;) )

That's done!

You could find documentation here :

- http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/17/replace.html
- http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/08/whats-new-git-2-1/ (Section `git replace got smarter`)

Comment: What do you do with the big_squash branch? In the current solution your master branch will still be the same.

Comment: doesnt work.. the branch big_squash ends up with just one commit "My new root". Even after running `git filter-branch master`

Comment: @vinaywadwa surely you forgot to do the `git replace` before

Comment: @volpato that's the goal of the `replace` that will 'hide' all the commits to squash by one and the `filter-branch` will rebuild all the branches history and update the sha1. 'master' will be modified, I could assure you!

Comment: For people who came after me: I corrected the code above, and it should work fine now. @Philippe, please update with instructions on how to revert changes before deleting `.git/refs/original`. I think this is the best solution, thanks for it!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a shallow clone via `git clone --depth 1000`. A shallow clone still has full commit power, see https://github.com/git/git/commit/82fba2b9d39163a0c9b7a3a2f35964cbc039e1a

You can even keep the old tree around in case you still need it and it's fully compatible, no need to change history.

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite get what you want, because you can't remove anything from a repository, you can only add new things to it.

To restate, but with a commit graph drawing, what you have now is (simplified):

```
<jumble of commits> - K - L - M - etc ...  <-- master
                        \      / (merges)  <-- etc
                        (branches)
```

and what you want (similarly simplified) is:

```
K - L - M - etc ...  <-- master
 \      / (merges)  <-- etc
 (branches)
```

so that `K` is now the root commit.

You can't get *that*, but you can get a *new* root commit that is *almost* exactly the same as `K`, with two big differences: a different SHA-1, and no parent commit ID(s).  The commit would have the same tree and all the same files as commit `K`.

Having copied `K` to `K'`, you can then copy `L` to `L'` and so on, so that what you get is a new commit graph that has the same shape and same files and so on, just with all-new SHA-1 IDs.

The git thing that does this is `filter-branch`.

There are at least two ways to achieve this with `filter-branch`.  One is to have a commit filter that:

- skips all commits until commit `K` appears, then
- copies all commits (including `K` itself)

(and then add the usual `--tag-name-filter cat` and so on).  This one is slightly painful as the commit filter is not `eval`-ed, so you have to "remember" the skip/keep state externally (e.g., in a file).

Another method is to use `--parent-filter` [as already described by Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29043295/1256452).

The difference between these is that the `--parent-filter` method is easier but copies all the "pre-`K`" commits too, so that you wind up with two independent graphs in your copy.  You might want this, or not; and if, after you clean out the `refs/original` name-space, there are no references to the "pre-`K'`" commits, they will be garbage-collected as usual, so that the difference goes away.

Comment: Any method of using `git filter-branch` will leave the old commits around, via the `refs/original/...` backup branch. Since the `--parent-filter` that I wrote only touches one commit, it will be a no-op for all of the commits earlier than that point, so they will be exactly the same commits that you have preserved in your `refs/original` backup branch.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: yes, true; I was mainly thinking about what happens after you've removed the `refs/original` backups.  If you omit the "copies" (which, as you note, really just re-use the original objects), filter-branch also does the "remap to ancestor" thing.  Assuming some earlier commit (say `E`) has a branch or tag pointing to it, if you "copy", it will still point to `E`.  I'm not actually sure what remap-to-ancestor does if E-and-earlier are all gone...